# Camera Bounds in perspective mode in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How Can I find extreme left, right, top, bottom points of perspective camera in Unity 3D. I am trying to do zooming and panning. I need those points to check if I am going out of my Bound. Is there any other way to find?

Answer (score 3):

This unity manual entry directly answers your question:

[FrustumSizeAtDistance](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html/)

So to summarize:

To calculate the height of the view frustum at a given distance we can calculate it like so:

`var frustumHeight = 2.0f * distance * Mathf.Tan(camera.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);`

If we already know the frustumHeight we can calculate the corresponding distance to the camera:

`var distance = frustumHeight * 0.5f / Mathf.Tan(camera.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);`

Once we have the frustumHeight at a given distance we can calculate its width by using the cameras aspect:

`var frustumWidth = frustumHeight * camera.aspect;`

This can also be reversed like so:

`var frustumHeight = frustumWidth / camera.aspect;`

Answer (score 1):

[`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) will assist you.

For instance, to find bottom-left point of the screen projected onto the world, use this:

```
camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, distance_from_camera));
```

Comment: and what about top right? when I use camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, distance_from_camera)); it gives me same value as 0, 0

Comment: @user2810313 that would be [`ViewportToWorldPoint`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html) or instead of **1** use screen's width and height.